# Copy files from remote Ubuntu to local Mac

Tags: ssh, mac, scp

I've searched all around and can't seem to find this... I'm trying to copy a private key to my local machine which is a Mac.

When I fire up terminal on my mac, I get 
`Jamies-iMac:~ jamie$`

So after I ssh into my Ubuntu server I tried

```
scp /path/to/myfile.txt jamie@Jamies-iMac:/path/to/myfile.txt
```

which gives me:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname Jamies-iMac: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

In place of `jamie@Jamies-iMac:/path/to/myfile.txt` I've tried some other variations but nothing seems to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

@ovc had it right, but there is a syntax error, and my edit got rejected for some reason. You need to have a colon between the user and filepath on the ubuntu side, and on the mac side you need to have the `/Users/username/` portion in the filepath. Like so:

```
scp username@192.168.1.111:/path/to/myfile.txt /Users/Jamie/local/path/to/myfile.txt
```

This assumes you have private key authentication set up.

Comment: Its showing "Permission Denied (public key)"

Comment: default port is 22, `-P` to specify port

Comment: Use `-r` to recursively copy a folder

Answer (score 19):

You're doing it the wrong way around. Simply use the scp command on the Mac, like this: `scp username@192.168.1.111:/path/to/myfile.txt /local/path/to/myfile.txt`. You may also just use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org) which is a graphical client. Connect to your Ubuntu with a URL like `sftp://192.168.1.111`, of course you need to use the valid IP address.

Comment: Ah, so I can only go one way. I knew it was something simple. Thanks.

Comment: I made a small edit to your answer, it didn't work until I did it the way that is shown in the edit.

Comment: inorganik, it can go both ways long as you have an SSH server running on *both* machines. I don't beleive that's the case with Macs, though. Otherwise, you'll need to use scp from the machine without the server so that it can perform a connection.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the graphical client option, I used Cyberduck and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 9):

Excellent answers above. Additionally, if you need to use a certificate for authentication, you can use the -i flag.

```
scp -i /path/to/cert username@192.168.1.111:/path/to/myfile.txt /Users/Jamie/local/path/to/myfile.txt
```

Comment: I didn't see your reply earlier, but this was what I needed. I  kind of deduced it from the answer above and then saw yours. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Proposition of a solution inspired by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/329372/1171734) .

In order to copy a file from a remote server to your local home computer you will need to open a terminal on your home computer and write a command structured like this :

```
scp -P $PORT_NUMBER $USERNAME@$IP_ADDRESS:$PATH_TO_THE_FILE_TO_COPY $PATH_TO_DESTINATION
```

---

**Explanations :**

```
scp :
```

Secure Copy command more infos [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles)

```
$PORT_NUMBER:
```

SSH have a default port set to 22, you can edit this port here ex: 23

```
$USERNAME:
```

the username access

```
$IP_ADDRESS:
```

the ip of the remote access

```
$PATH_TO_THE_FILE_TO_COPY:
```

the path where you want to get the file

```
$PATH_TO_DESTINATION:
```

the path where you want to copy the file

---

**For exemple :**

```
scp -P 22 johndoe@$011.235.813.213:/var/projects/calculator/tests/week-1 /Users/John/transit/
```

---

**Advices :**

- Be sure to have the necessary rights on the element you want to copy
  from your server.
- ⚠️ Init this command from your home computer not from the server ⚠️

---

Answer (score 1):

If the path you're using has spaces, you should use the path in quotes, such as

```
scp username@192.168.1.111:"/path to/myfile.txt" ./myfile.txt
```

Yet, that didnt work for me.

Allegedly you should use triple backslashes, such as

```
/Users/me/Application\\\ Data/file.txt
```

But it worked with path in quotes and double slashes only.

I am ssh-ing from a mac into another mac though.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to open the terminal in your local Mac
2. In the terminal type the below command

   scp user@59.119.31.42:/tmp/server_db_backup/db.sql /Users/username/Desktop/

In the above command

- "59.119.31.42" should be replaced with your server IP
- "/tmp/server_db_backup/db.sql" this should be replaced with the path of the file in the server
- "/Users/username/Desktop/" this should be replaced with the local path where you are going to save that file

If you need to pass the certificate to login then run the below command where need to replace the all the above and the path/to/key.pem according to your key location

```
scp -i /path/to/key.pem user@59.119.31.42:/tmp/server_db_backup/db.sql /Users/username/Desktop/
```