# Using scp to copy files from remote to home machine

Tags: networking, server, ssh, scp

This is probably a simple error, but I can't work it out.
My computer hostname is Felix (`hostname -f` returns Felix)
I am trying to move a file from my university account to my home computer using scp.
I can ssh easily to the remote computer so that connection is fine, the scp syntax I am using is (whilst connected to remote computer via ssh):

```
scp myusername@university_computer:/home/myusername/file.odt homeusername@Felix:Desktop/file.odt
```

I have tried a number of variations of this, and the error it returns is:

```
ssh: Felix: Name or service not known
```

Which suggests to me that using `homeusername@Felix` isn't the right syntax to be using.

I am not a superuser on the university system and only have access to my files, so cannot access any system files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You do not need to specify your local hostname to `scp` a file from your university computer. What you need to do is from your home computer open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following command:

```
scp myusername@university_computer:/home/myusername/file.odt /local/destination/path/
```

where `/local/destination/path` is the local path on `Felix` where you wish to store the file.

Comment: And of course the command is being run from the local machine

Comment: Most people miss the fact that it has to be run from local machine and not from the server side.

Answer (score 5):

i had the exact same problem and this tutorial helped me a lot:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles

Answer (score 2):

Ok...couple problems here. You DO NOT need to have the first address if you are on said computer. Lets say you are on comp A. A does not need to have its address written. B needs its IP address written, not its hostname. So... it would be scp /home/user/file username@000.000.000.000:/home/user/

You need your address there, not your hostname. So Felix has nothing to do with this. Do ifconifg and look for your ip, while on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
scp <remote-user-name>@<ec2-endpoint>:/home/<remote-user-name>/<file-to-be-copied> ./Desktop/
```

This will copy the remote ec2-instance file in you `Desktop` folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and the GUI:

[image]