# How can i access others machine terminal through my machine?

Tags: network-manager, virtualization, remote-access

is there any command or way to access the other machine terminal into mine to execute commands for other machine that is on the same network.

Comment: easiest way installing team viewer or vnc try to search adding to ubuntu

Comment: You are probably looking for SSH.

Comment: @edwinksl https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/

Comment: through this SSH can we able to execute commands on others machine

Comment: @MirzaHassanAliBaig Yes. Read the page I linked.

Comment: @guntbert I think the answers to that question aren't comprehensive enough regarding installation and setup for it to be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Install the ssh server on the remote machine if it isn't already installed. (requires package `openssh-server` on remote machine, to get the remote machine set up, follow this guide: [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring))

Then use the command from your computer, where "john" is the username of the user you want to log into the remote machine with, and "1.2.3.4" is that machines ip.

`ssh john@1.2.3.4`

You'll be prompted for the password of that user on that machine.

To set up more secure access, use this command(s)

`ssh-keygen`

Follow prompts.

`ssh-copy-id john@1.2.3.4`

Enter password one last time, and now you no longer need to use a password for user john when using ssh to access 1.2.3.4 .

This is more secure as you can disable password authentication in `sshd-config`. See: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#Disable_Password_Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

ssh to login and run commands

scp to copy files

Can also use sftp to copy files

previous question and answers on scp [Using scp to copy files from remote to home machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329370/using-scp-to-copy-files-from-remote-to-home-machine)

A bit more advanced
If you need to run commands or programs that will take a while to run and you don't want to disconnect your session - You could use screen, tmux or byobu.