# How to Download a file from a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04 to my local machine

Tags: server, ssh

I created a chaincoin masternode on a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04.  It uses an SSH cert I created to secure it.  Now I would like to download my wallet.dat file from the server onto my local machine.  I know the file path in ubuntu but as this wallet.dat file contains valuable cryptocurrency I want to make sure I don't mess it up. I used this guide: http://www.chaincoin.org/Setting%20up%20a%20Chaincoin%20Masternode%20-%20draft%20v.04.pdf  to setup the node - so you can see exactly what's on the server.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How to DL  you mean download ?

Comment: yes I meant download - specifically download to my local machine

Comment: okay check our this answer it could help you :) https://askubuntu.com/questions/312697/copy-files-from-remote-ubuntu-to-local-mac

Comment: Will do, thx :)

Comment: I created a dummy test file to test this on and so far I'm not having any luck.  I'm on a windows PC that doesn't have Ubuntu running locally, ubuntu is running on a rented server on the cloud which I'm sure complicates things, and all I'm trying to do is send test.txt to my local machine.  Thx for your input and patience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy files over ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646443/copy-files-over-ssh)

Answer (score 1):

You said you use windows, but not which version of windows. Windows 10 has [Linux subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide). If you have Windows 10, the link should show you how to enable/use Linux subsystem under windows 10. Once you have it setup and running, you can use a program under Ubuntu called rsync to securely download file from remote linux server using ssh like this:

```
rsync -chavzP --stats user@remote.host:/path/to/copy /path/to/local/storage
```

rsync ensures integrity of the file, ssh ensures file transferred securely.

There is a second easier way to do it. but it's not too secure and file might get corrupted, if it's a large file and your internet line is dodgy.

Install apache web server on remote server `sudo apt install apache2` then cp your wallet file to apache root folder like this: `cp wallet.dat /var/www/html` after that just open you browser and download the file by going to `http://your ip of server/wallet.dat`.

Hopefully one of the method works for you.

Comment: Windows 7 unfortunately...  but I'll try the second method with my test file.  Any additional advice is as always much appreiciated.

Comment: also, when you say "cp" you mean copy correct?

Comment: the name of the command is 'cp' as exactly shown. There is no command called copy in linux.

Comment: lol ok, learn something new everyday.... except for the last week where I've learned seveal thousand things... lol

Comment: as long as you are learning :) I was lost when I started out with linux 15 years ago, and I still don't know a lot of things and learning almost everyday.

Comment: Yup that's where I am now :)

Comment: Installed Apache2 and I'm getting this error while trying to cp test.txt          cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/html/test.txt': Permission denied

Comment: try sudo before cp.